# URL is generating a /#!/splash-page

Tags: seo, htaccess, web-development, url-rewriting

My site for some reason is generating a shebang - `/#!/splash-page` on the URL. For example when I type `www.modernvintage1005.com`, the browser returns `www.modernvintage1005.com/#!/splash-page` and every subsequent page is `/#!/about`, `/#!/contact`, and so forth.

There's absolutely nothing on the Google about this. There is a lot of rewrite help to eliminate `.index.php` from the home page, but that's it.

How do I rewrite it to just say `domain.com` and `domain.com/about.html`, etc.?

Here is my *.htaccess* file if you need to see it.

```
# Rewrite Rule
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddType x-font/otf .otf
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddType x-font/eot .eot
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/png .png
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 4):

The "hashbang" or "shebang" url syntax is an old hack designed to provide browser history to AJAX sites and to help Google index content that is loaded via JavaScript. See ["What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) for more.

Your WordPress theme, "John Smith", is responsible for rewriting URLs in this way. It does this so that it can load each page using JavaScript without a full page refresh and still make the content accessible to [Google's crawlers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more). (This is what the "AJAX" in the "AJAX Portfolio Theme" refers to.) It is nothing to do with your `.htaccess` file.

A lot of webmasters now feel that using the hashbang URL syntax is a bad idea for the [reasons stayed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438383/88487) – it is not very future-proof, and there are now better options available. (i.e. ["pushState"](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/), an HTML5 feature that allows developers to modify the browser URL without refreshing the page.)

Your options are to:

- Contact the theme developer and ask them if there is an option to turn off the AJAX functionality in their theme to remove the hashbang URLs.
- Contact the theme developer and ask them to consider modifying the theme to use `pushState` instead of `location.hash`. (Refer them to [this article](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate).) This would give you URLs with no hashbang, which sounds like what you want.
- Use a different WordPress theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I read up on this on another answer from another forum and there is a lot of common views. However, there is a chatter that the use of shebangs may actually be better for SEO than not to have them. If that is the case, I'd consider keeping them. What is your take on that?

Comment: Using `pushState` should not make sites any less crawlable. See [this post](http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate) from moz.com, who now recommend it over the `#!` hack. Just make sure that the URL you update with `pushState` loads identical content with JavaScript turned off. With WordPress, this is easy – you just need to make sure pretty permalinks are turned on. The only other consideration is that older browsers don't support `pushState`, but developers can use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to work around that.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. I'm on a mission now

Comment: By the way, I guess I need more reputation to vote your answer up. Sorry. I would if I could